# Qual o comando linux utilizado para descobrir quem é o pai de um processo?

Tags: linux

**Gostaria de saber qual o comando no terminal do Linux para descobrir o PID do pai de um processo.**

Alguém sabe quem é o pai do processo **upstart**?

Por exemplo:

Eu executei o: **ps aux**

E peguei o **PID** do processo **upstart**.

O processo upstart tem o **PID (1430)**.

Como faço para descobrir o PID do pai desse processo (upstart).

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/150117?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ps axf` e veja em forma de árvore, assim fica bem fácil encontrar os processos dependentes.

```
15732 pts/1    Ss     0:00  \_ bash
26695 pts/1    S+     0:00  |   \_ make watch WATCHMAKE=dev -j64 --keep-going ...
26704 pts/1    S+     0:00  |       \_ bash -c while true; do \ ?make dev -j64 ...
28993 pts/1    S+     0:00  |           \_ inotifywait -qre close_write ...
16239 pts/2    Ss     0:00  \_ bash
16775 pts/2    Sl+    0:33  |   \_ icemon
31755 pts/5    Ss     0:00  \_ bash
31816 pts/5    S      0:00  |   \_ su
31817 pts/5    S      0:00  |       \_ bash
31840 pts/5    S      0:00  |           \_ sudo -u buildbot bash
31841 pts/5    S      0:00  |               \_ bash
32065 pts/5    S+     0:00  |                   \_ tail -f twistd.log
```